# JavaScript Not Adding To List also no error messages

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, sorting, for-loop

```
class Card{
    constructor(letter, value) {
        this.letter = letter;
        this.value = value;

    }

    type() {
        
        return this.letter + " of " + this.value;
    
    }

}
const letterlist = ['Ace', 'Hearts'];
const valuelist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const Cardlist = [];

for (let i = 0; i < letterlist; i++){
    
    for (let x = 0; x < valuelist; x++){

        Cardlist.push(new Card(letterlist[i], valuelist[x]));
    

}

}

for (let i = 0; i < Cardlist; i++){
    
    console.log(Cardlist[i]);
}
```

I am trying to make make objectes inside my cardlist but it is not working. I am new to javascript and was wondering why my code exucutes fully without giving me error messages in vscode in terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating over an entire array instead of the length of the array.

You should change the following lines:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < letterlist.length; i++){     // <- added ".length" to letterlist
    for (let x = 0; x < valuelist.length; x++){ // <- added ".length" to valuelist
```

```js
for (let i = 0; i < Cardlist.length; i++){ // <- added ".length" to Cardlist
```

Here is a working snippet:

```js
class Card{
constructor(letter, value) {
    this.letter = letter;
    this.value = value;

}

type() {
    
    return this.letter + " of " + this.value;

}

}
const letterlist = ['Ace', 'Hearts'];
const valuelist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const Cardlist = [];

for (let i = 0; i < letterlist.length; i++){

for (let x = 0; x < valuelist.length; x++){

    Cardlist.push(new Card(letterlist[i], valuelist[x]));


}

}

for (let i = 0; i < Cardlist.length; i++){

console.log(Cardlist[i].type());
}
```